Trying for get f2py to work on fib example
I have been trying to get f2py to run the fib example on the web. In my last effort I
removed python and reinstalled python with MINGW64 as a command window. The f2py command fails on what it appears to be compiling a program. I have installed  the gcc compilers and tested the fortran, c, c++ compilers from the command line. I can not find a command line argument that passes the compiler path into f2py.
the following is what happens when I try the fib example:
Jack@DESKTOP-AEVARBH MINGW64 ~
$ f2py -c fib1.f -m fib
Cannot use distutils backend with Python>=3.12, using meson backend instead.
Using meson backend
Will pass --lower to f2py
See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/buildtools/meson.html
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'fib1.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
        Block: fib
                        Block: fib
Applying post-processing hooks...
  character_backward_compatibility_hook
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "fib"...
    Generating possibly empty wrappers"
    Maybe empty "fib-f2pywrappers.f"
        Constructing wrapper function "fib"...
          fib(a,[n])
    Wrote C/API module "fib" to file ".\fibmodule.c"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Scripts\f2py.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 765, in          main
    run_compile()
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 737, in run_compile
    builder.compile()
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\_backends\_meson.py", line 178, in compile
    self.run_meson(self.build_dir)
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\_backends\_meson.py", line   171, in run_meson
    self._run_subprocess_command(setup_command, build_dir)
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\_backends\_meson.py", line 167, in _run_subprocess_command
     subprocess.run(command, cwd=cwd, check=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

On previous tris under different software installs the code has failed at the same spot.
I have put a print statement into
  File "C:\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

The result was executable=None. The args=[ menson and two other arguments I have forgotten.
I am at a loss and I might give up the project if a solution is not found.
I am running Windows 10 64 bit machine. The version number for python id 3.12 and for number is 2.0.0.

f2py can't run meson for build module (FileNotFoundError...). Under python 3.12, f2py need meson, ninja, cmake and, for some cases, charset-normalizer and pkgconfig.

Thank you. The missing packages were the problem. The error occurs  both under running f2py under python and using a command line.
